# Safari not opening local html files after upgrading to macOS Catalina Beta

Tags: macos, safari, catalina, beta

I recently upgraded to macOS Catalina (10.15 Beta (19A546d)) on my Mid 2014 MacBook Pro. Then I can not open local html files on Safari (13.0 (15608.2.5)) and got the following error message. However, I can open websites on Safari and local html files on Chrome and Firefox. I don't have any third-party security software.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug that you should report to Apple as part of the beta process.

Comment: I've been having this issue with the last few versions of Mojave, which have been fixed in the Safari Technology Preview. But not in Catalina, odd. It could be a bug you need to file using the Feedback Assistant. You could see if the location of the file has any effect on the error.

Comment: Problem Solved! It turns out that Safari did not have permission to read my html files. Go to System Preference > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access and add safari. I'm not an expert, so I'm not aware of other negative consequences of this action.

Comment: @Purple_Wind Please promote that to an answer. It would help more people like me!

Answer (score 10):

It turns out that Safari did not have permission to read my html files. Go to

> System Preference > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access

and add safari. (Answer taken from comment.)